# Exp:resso Store and Zoo Visitor shipping informations problem

Tags: expresso-store, zoo-visitor, shipping

Hello I'm having problems with the checkout tags and the shipping address features of Store from Exp:resso. I'm using Zoo Visitor and I've set up Store to map order fields with Zoo Visitor member fields. When the Zoo Vistor shipping member fields are set, if I try to checkout my cart, the shipping address will be the same as billing, it won't take the shipping mapped member fields to pre-fill the form.

If I complete my checkout, the changes I made in my shipping address will be saved in the Zoo Visitor profile, but if I try to checkout another cart, it will fulfill the shipping address with the billing one again.

I know I can build up my own inputs, and I could try to grab the data from the Zoo Visitor profile, but isn't order fields mapping supposed to solve this, even for shipping infos ?

Thanks for your help !

**Checkout Template** :
I'm using the one from Store, pretty much unchanged

```
{exp:store:checkout
form_class="form-horizontal"
next="site/checkout2"
error_handling="inline"
error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'
require="name|address1|address3|country"}

{if no_items}
    {redirect="site/checkout"}
{/if}

<fieldset id="billing_details">
    <legend>Billing Details</legend>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_name}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_name">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_name} {error:billing_name}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_address1}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_address1">Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_address1} {error:billing_address1}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_address2}error{/if}">
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_address2} {error:billing_address2}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_address3}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_address3">City</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_address3} {error:billing_address3}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_postcode}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_postcode">Postcode</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_postcode} {error:billing_postcode}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_country}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_country">Country</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_country} {error:billing_country}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_phone}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_phone">Phone</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_phone} {error:billing_phone}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:order_email}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="order_email">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:order_email} {error:order_email}
        </div>
    </div>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Shipping Details</legend>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label for="shipping_same_as_billing" class="checkbox">
                {field:shipping_same_as_billing} Same as Billing Details
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="shipping_details_drawer">

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_name}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_name">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="shipping_name" value="{shipping_name}" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_address1}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_address1">Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_address1} {error:shipping_address1}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_address2}error{/if}">
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_address2} {error:shipping_address2}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_address3}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_address3">City</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_address3} {error:shipping_address3}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_postcode}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_postcode">Postcode</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_postcode} {error:shipping_postcode}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_country}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_country">Country</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_country} {error:shipping_country}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_phone}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_phone">Phone</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_phone} {error:shipping_phone}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</fieldset>

<div class="form-actions">
    <a href="{path='site/checkout'}" class="btn">Back</a>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Review Order" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>


{/exp:store:checkout}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#shipping_same_as_billing').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#shipping_details_drawer').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('#shipping_details_drawer').slideDown();
        }
    });
    if ($('#shipping_same_as_billing').is(':checked')) {
        $('#shipping_details_drawer').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you open up Store > Settings > General and scroll down to "Default Shipping Address" unless you have changed it would be set to "Shipping same as Billing" change that to "None" and save. You will need to empty your cart to clear the session data but you should now see the fields being populated by your ZooVisitor field data for the shipping fields now.